# Try catch always return error when I insert 2 data

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5.4

I want to add function check quantity stock If I add 1 data It's work but after I insert 2 data It will get an error here is my controller

```
 $i = 0;
        $sum = 0;
        $count = count($request->get('quantity_box'));
        $a = "INV".rand(10,99).$ldate.rand(10,9);
        $errors = false;

        try {
                DB::transaction(function () use ($count,$request,$a,$errors) {
                for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                    print_r($i);
                    $warehouse_products_sell = New Warehouse_products_sell;
                    $id_w = $request->input('idw');
                    $id_c = $request->get('id_c')[$i];
                    $id_p = $request->get('id_p')[$i];
                    $qty = $request->input('quantity_box')[$i];
                    $price = $request->input('price')[$i];
                    $available = $this->check_stock($id_w, $id_p, $qty);   
                    if($available > 0){
                        $warehouse_products_sell->add_by = $request->input('add_by');
                        $warehouse_products_sell->save();
                    }else{
                       throw new \Exception('Error');
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $errors = $e;
        }
```

when I print `$errors` It show up .  'Exception' with message 'Error'

I try to check this query by remove try catch and add 2 data, it's work fine .  not sure how to check this error

here is my html form input

```
<input type="text" name="quantity_box[]" class="form-control" autofocus="" />
```

Comment: The prolem here is that for some of the given products `check_stock` return false (your $qty bigger than the stock for that product)  so the bloc `else{
                       throw new \Exception('Error');
                    }` will be executed so throwing an exception :)

Comment: oh thank you it's you again lol @Maraboc

Comment: Hi so you can custumize the message in the exception like this `throw new \Exception('The quantity '.$qty.' is not available in stock for the this product id '.$id_p);` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i figure it out

in My html should

```
<input type="text" name="quantity_box[0]" class="form-control" autofocus="" />
```